# Spartan 6: How do I use my differential clock?

Tags: fpga, spartan

my SP601 Evaluation Board comes with one 2.5 V LVDS differential 200 MHz Oscillator. Until now, I have only been using the single-ended clock provided with the board. I am having trouble with how to format the user constraints file to use the differential clock. Here is what I have in my user constraints file so far.

```
NET "clk_N" LOC = "K16"; ## 5 on U5 EG2121CA, 5 of U20 SI500D (DNP)
NET "clk_P" LOC = "K15"; ## 6 on U5 EG2121CA, 4 of U20 SI500D (DNP)
```

What I had before, when I used the single-ended clock, was:

```
NET "clk" LOC = "V10"; ## 5 on X2 USER OSC Socket
NET "clk" TNM_NET = "clk";
TIMESPEC "TS_clk" = PERIOD "clk" 37 ns HIGH 50%;
```

In addition, after I successfully include the clock in my user constraints file, what changes do I have to make to my code to switch from the single-ended clock to the differential clock? Originally, I have one signal called `clk`, and I trigger off the rising edge of this signal. Now that I have two signals, the rising edge method doesn't seem like it'll work. Should I make a new signal that is `clk_1` - `clk_2`, where `clk_1` and `clk_2` are the two differential signals? I don't know if changing my clock source should affect how the rest of my code is written.

What I am saying is that I am new to FPGAs, and I have an idea of how differential signaling works in theory, but I'm not sure how it works out in practice. I'm using VHDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constraints, do something like this:

```
NET "clk_P" LOC = "K15" | IOSTANDARD=LVDS_33; ## 6 on U5 EG2121CA, 4 of U20 SI500D (DNP)
NET "clk_N" LOC = "K16" | IOSTANDARD=LVDS_33; ## 5 on U5 EG2121CA, 5 of U20 SI500D (DNP)
NET "clk_P" TNM_NET = "clk";
TIMESPEC "TS_clk" = PERIOD "clk" 5 ns HIGH 50%;
```

You only need to constrain the P side, as per http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/57109.html .  Make sure you get the right IOSTANDARD.  Perhaps LVPECL_25, LVPECL_33, LVDS_25, or LVDS_33, depending on the clock source.  See Xilinx UG381.  You may also need to set DIFF_TERM = TRUE along with IOSTANDARD to enable internal 100 ohm differential termination.  Check the board layout/schematic to see if there is already a discrete termination resistor, in which case you should leave DIFF_TERM off or add DIFF_TERM = FALSE.

Then you will need to instantiate an IBUFGDS instead of an IBUFG, perhaps something like this:

```
IBUFGDS ibufg_inst (.I(clk_P), .IB(clk_N), .O(clk_ibufg));
BUFG bufg_inst (.I(clk_ibufg), .O(clk));
```

Then just use clk as you did before.  Is you're using a DCM or PLL, you should be able to put the DCM or PLL instance in between the IBUFGDS and the BUFG.

Comment: One should also check the schematic to see if internal termination is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was getting to that.  I presume it's going to be needed, not sure why a designer would opt for a discrete termination resistor for a differential clock input like that.  It could be difficult to get it in the correct location on the board.

Comment: I've seen it on Xilinx dev boards before, not sure if there's a reason.

Comment: Is FD_100 an actual setting? I thought it was DIFF_TERM = TRUE.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is just DIFF_TERM = TRUE.  There is a whole table in UG381 of different termination styles with names that look like they could go in the UCF file, like FD_100 and FP_VCCO_50, NS_70_ND_187_FD_100, etc.

Comment: On further reading, it looks like IN_TERM and OUT_TERM are for single-ended signalling only, and there is only the DIFF_TERM for a 100 ohm termination for differential signalling.

Comment: Would I then write this? 



NET clk_P DIFF_TERM = TRUE;

Comment: Just add it after IOSTANDARD and separate with another |

Comment: But I suppose putting it on its own line would work as well